# Counterintuitive behaviour of `list(itertools.groupy)`

Tags: python, group-by, python-itertools

Let me demonstrate. It has bitten me twice and first time I gave up thinking that I can't understand how `groupby` works. I am using `Python3.6'.

I have a list of elements in `x.y` format which I want to groupby `y`.

```
a = ['1D.5', '2D.5', '3D.5', '1D.10', '2D.10', '3D.10', '1D.20', '2D.20', '3D.20', '1D.100', '2D.100', '3D.100']
groups = list(itertools.groupby(a, key=lambda x: x.split('.')[-1]))
for gname, glist in groups:
    print(list(glist))
```

This results in following.

```
[]
[]
[]
['3D.100']
```

Strange!

However this works.

```
groups = itertools.groupby(a, key=lambda x: x.split('.')[-1])
for gname, glist in groups:
    print(list(glist))

['1D.5', '2D.5', '3D.5']
['1D.10', '2D.10', '3D.10']
['1D.20', '2D.20', '3D.20']
['1D.100', '2D.100', '3D.100']
```

The difference being that this time I didn't call `list` on the `itertools.groupby`. Definately there is some technical reason behind this behaviour, but with experience I have about python generators, this is very counterintuitive and probably wrong!

Why would calling `list` on an iterator invalidate its content?

**PS:**
The docuementation of `groupby` has following two lines in its implementation details.

```
# [k for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')] --> A B C D A B
# [list(g) for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCD')] --> AAAA BBB CC D
```

Am I right in suspecting `list(some generator)` is not guarenteed to give the same results as "equivalent" list comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby`'s group iterators are dependent on the prior ones. So the proper way to make a list out of those group iterators is to ensure that you copy each one as it is produced.

```
list((g, list(it)) for g, it in itertools.groupby(a, key=func))
```

The outer `list` alone will not copy the inner iterators `it` that can only be accessed once and only in sequence.